Can I use the NEEWER QPRO-N on Canon R6 with NEEWER Z2-C 2,4G TTL Flash units if I don't need ETTL?
I would like to buy the QPRO-C TTL Wireless Flash Trigger but it is currently out of stock everywhere I looked. So I am wondering if I could just buy the N version for example to bridge the estimated 6 months for new C versions to arrive.
I don't plan on using TTL in the meantime and focus on learning everything in manual. But will the N version be triggered by my Canon camera (EOS R6) and will the trigger in turn activate the C version speedlights (NEEWER Z2-C 2,4G TTL).
And more importantly will I be able to change settings remotely?

I'm not going to put this in answer because it's opinion, but if you're starting from scratch also consider Godox. They're pretty much functionally identical to Neewer, priced about the same, and at least as reliable. Plus Godox tends to introduce new features first, then Neewer clones them.

Now that the equipment has arrived and I have been able to test how it works, I can confirm that:

the remote control can fully control the flashes (including zoom settings etc.)
the remote control triggers the flashes without any problems
of course the control via the camera or via TTL does NOT work

This means that the trigger can be combined with flashes of other types (here N trigger with C speedlights) without any problems, as the transmission protocol between the flash and trigger does not differ, only the hotshoe is set up differently.
Therefore no matching version is required to dial in the settings manually via the remote control and to trigger the flash.

Theoretically, yes. But it's possible all you'd be able to do is fire the flash remotely from the transmitter. You might have M power by group control. But no TTL, HSS, or zooming. The only signal the two hotshoes have in common is the sync (fire) signal, which is part of the ISO standard.
See also: Is flash brand X compatible with camera brand Y?
However, I'm seeing the QPro-C in stock on Amazon in the US at the moment. Are you sure you have to wait for six months to find one?

If all one could do with the QPRO-N is fire the Canon version flashes, the Q Compact single should trigger Neewer Q3 system flashes for 1/3 the price of the QPRO-N?

I am located in Gemany and have not found any offer online with available stock appart from Alibaba, which seems a bit scetchy... Even on the Neewer website it states "out of stock"

@Jan_B, not helpful, but I note the Godox V1C and Xpro II-C and X3-C are all in stock on amazon.de. Godox's system is more popular and more expandable than the Neewer Q system. Maybe consider exchanging the Z2C for a Godox V1C?
